Pointing multiple domains to same server: LiteSpeed Web Server Enterprise
I'm wondering if someone can help me with this.
I have tracking software running on a domain called app.tracking-domain.com. This is hosted on a self-managed LiteSpeed Web Server Enterprise; no control panels, such as c-pannel, are installed.
I want to use a custom domain to keep the original app.tracking-domain.com private and secure.
This custom domain would be track.custom-domain.com
For this, I want to point track.custom-domain.com to the same virtual host as app.tracking-domain.com. Basically, both app.tracking-domain.com and track.custom-domain.com should point to the exact server location.
I wonder how I can get this done on the LiteSpeed Web Server.
So far, I tried adding a virtual host and settings as follows. This gives me 404, but testing page doesn't load.
 Basic >> Base
    Virtual Host Name:  track.custom-domain.com
    Virtual Host Root:  $SERVER_ROOT/app.tracking-domain.com/
    Config File :   $SERVER_ROOT/conf/vhosts/app.tracking-domain.com/vhconf.conf
 
General >> General
    Document Root:  /usr/local/lsws/app.tracking-domain.com/html/

Also tested as follows;
Basic >> Base
    Virtual Host Name:  track.custom-domain.com
    Virtual Host Root:  $SERVER_ROOT/track.custom-domain.com/
   Config File  :   $SERVER_ROOT/conf/vhosts/$VH_NAME/vhconf.conf
 
General >> General
    Document Root:  /usr/local/lsws/app.tracking-domain.com/html/

